# how to convert existing android project into gradle dependency

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, dependencies

How do I convert existing android project into gradle dependency so that it can be used in other project just by adding dependency to gradle file?

Answer (score 2):

Create a library module.

1. Open the module-level build.gradle file.
   Delete the line for the applicationId. Only an Android app module can define this.
2. At the top of the file, you should see the following:

   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

Change it to the following:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

3. Import the library module to your project (the library source becomes part of your project):
   a. Click File > New > Import Module.
   b. Enter the location of the library module directory then click Finish.
   The library module is copied to your project, so you can actually edit the library code.
4. Make sure the library is listed at the top of your settings.gradle file, as shown here for a library named "my-library-module":

   include ':app', ':my-library-module'
5. Open the app module's build.gradle file and add a new line to the dependencies block as shown in the following snippet:

   dependencies {
       implementation project(":my-library-module")
   }

https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library#Convert